# Nighttime "light on dark" skin

Tags: feature-request, design, mobile-web

It would be good to be able to view SO using light text on dark background.

The use case is evening or night on a mobile device when you don't want alert your significant other that you're lurking on SO, which has quite distinctively bright, mostly white pixel, pages.

It may also reduce battery use.

Comment: I know there are dups, but the reasons for the request is different

Comment: At night, lurk at http://scifi.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Just turn down the brightness on your device.

Comment: "It may also reduce battery use." [Not necessarily.](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5043/do-bright-wallpapers-spend-more-battery-than-dark-ones)

Comment: Just hug your significant other and forget coding? ;)

Comment: I'm really curious to know why same duplicate question got 12+ upvote but this one -7 Downvotes. Questions are identical. What gives? I leave it to the reader of this post to judge ...

Comment: One could only guess @SNash, but the fact that it's a duplicate could mean that the downvotes are for a lack of research. Or times might have changed over almost 2 years. Users might have a different view on the request than they had back then. That happens more often. The community evolves. Results of the past are no guarantees for the future. ;)

Comment: @SNash My questions generally get hammered here. Maybe it's personal :/

Comment: Unlikely @Bohemian. All those that do have a negative score are feature requests. And even some of those requests of yours are positively scored. You just have an unlucky hand at suggesting features.

Answer (score 7):

How about this extension for google chrome:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/high-contrast/djcfdncoelnlbldjfhinnjlhdjlikmph

[image]

Comment: Would be nice, but not supported for chrome on iPhone (5)

Comment: @Bohemian: hmm, you might be out of luck then unfortunately.