# Night view for StackOverflow mobile app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, ios-app

There were similar feature-requests for website version of SO.
Here are how they suggested and struggled.
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113089/257732
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194302/257732

But,I think there will be no need to describe why we need night view of mobile app for night-owls.

Comment: Why not turn down the screen brightness?

Comment: Black theme and lowering brightness are different. They use different color schemes. So they affect the eyes differently. It is not essential but it is needed on devices which are still bright with minimum adjustment at night.

Comment: You can invert colors at the system level on iOS.

Comment: I meant for Android app. There is no way to change colors at system level in Android stock ROMs.

Comment: @johnkarka Sorry!. Didn't see the tag.